# how to iterate over a strict list of files with python to make a tar of them

Tags: python, path, tar

using python3 (in a venv)

I am looking for a way to save some files, each strictly defined as its own full pathname in a variable

I would do something looking like this:

```py
import datetime
import os
import tarfile
import time

outputfilename = "backup.configfiles"   # as far as it has datetime names can't be similar
configfilelist = [
        "/app1/DATA2/tartes/titi",
        "/app2/DATA2/tartes/toto",
        "/app3/DATA8/tartes/truc"
        ]
# and so on for all of the filenames (here is only example of list)

def definetarfilename():
        # adapt date & time to file name
        t = time.localtime()
        timestamp = str(time.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M',t))
        global filedatee
        filedatee=outputfilename+"."+timestamp+".tar.gz"

def writefilestotargz():
        # use compression with gz
        with tarfile.open(filedatee, "w|gz") as tar:
                for f in [configfilelist]:
                        tar.add(f)

definetarfilename()     # generate filename
writefilestotargz()     # write tar.gz file
exit()
```

but I get errors about :

```
AttributeError: "list" object has no attribute "statswith"
```

I'm still new to python, so can you help define why and how I can fix that (method, syntax ?)

Comment: please include the full error message and traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a minor issue in `writefilestotargz` function:

```py
def writefilestotargz():
    # use compression with gz
    with tarfile.open(filedatee, "w|gz") as tar:
        for f in configfilelist:
            tar.add(f)
```

Comment: Namely, what is the issue?

Comment: `configfilelist` is defined as a list earlier in the code. When you write `for f in [configfilelist]:`, you're making another list out of it and iterating over that (i.e., `[configfilelist]`) which has one element, that is `configfilelist`.